# 90's US animated show, underwater lab is caving in, robot survives and is looking for "Joan"

Tags: story-identification, animation

I have a memory of a show I used to watch obsessively as a kid, I might have had it on tape. I've been trying to identify it for years. It might have been *Johnny Quest* or something similar/ripoff.

All I remember is the group is in some underwater lab, and it starts caving in. The robot member of the group makes it to the surface, swims to shore(?), and is stumbling around calling out for "Joan". It's going, "Joan... Juh-own.... Juh-own...."

Comment: When were you a kid/what year would this have been? When you say "show" do you mean it was a short single episode of something? Was this animated--and if so what did the animation look like?

Comment: I'm guessing you're the same fellow as at https://ask.metafilter.com/304691/Looking-for-an-80s-cartoon-with-a-robot-saying-Joan/amp

Comment: @FuzzyBoots yep, some good leads there but never found it. Good eye!

Comment: @Kitkat - animated kids episodic tv series. Would have been mid-to-late 80's. If I am remembering clearly in any way - which is never guaranteed - the animation was akin to He-Man, Transformers, Scooby Doo(?) - medium-budget 2-d cel animation.

Comment: Possibly an episode of [_Captain Future_](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0122336/?ref_=adv_li_tt), which has robots and a main character named Joan.  But it's late 70s and I can't find that particular episode

Comment: @SteveV that looks _fantastic_, but i don't think that's it. The synopses don't sound familiar at all. (But they do sound awesome.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it actually is [*Captain Future*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0122336).  Specifically an episode that translates to something like *The Underwater Trap*.  I was able download a German version of it (it's apparently a cult classic there).  In this episode, a water lab sinks/explodes.  Captain Future is trapped but gets out.  And Joan is held captive while a robot goes through the jungle looking for her calling out "Joan... Jooooan... Joaaan..."  (in German in the version I saw, probably the English was slightly different).  The German title is *Die Unterwasser-Falle*.  In the imdb comments on the series, someone mentions a VHS release in English with eight of the episodes.  I found the VHS covers for the two volume English set.

[image]

Here are some screen captures to see if it looks familiar:

Clip of Robot calling out (German)

Robot pic
[image]

Joan being captured

[image]

Lab sinking

[image]

Comment: Joan had really a solid chin.  Does anyone know which of [Hamilton's novels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Future) this is the adaptation of? Semi-related, the Japanese covers for the novels are [here](http://wwwcapitaineflam.free.fr/The_Complete_Captain_Future.pdf), but Joan Randall weirdly looks she's from high school. And if you want to destroy your childhood memories, ["The Death of Captain Future"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Future#%22The_Death_of_Captain_Future%22) is what's needed.

Comment: Well, that's got to be it - how many robots searching for Joan after an underwater collapse could there be, after all? But it doesn't feel like it. I don't remember those little creatures. Certainly the robot's voice is different - my memory is of a monotonous voice, and it says, "juh-own" with a hesitation in-between the syllables. But the difference is likely the German vs. American dub. And the image of the lab sinking does feel vaguely familiar. Is there any way to watch a US version?
Oh, and - THANK YOU! This has been nagging me for years, and I think you've squashed it.

Comment: That Asimov series sounds interesting. Is there anywhere to watch these in English?